# Applcation pool claiming more private memory if physical memory is added

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory, application-pool, iis-8.5

Good day,

Our production servers (w2k2012 with iis8.x) got a memory upgrade recently from 4GB to 8GB. The reason was that application pools (20-30, one per mvc/.net application were claiming too much memory (reaching the 5% limit).

We used the private bytes claimed by the worker processes to find out how much memory was reserved per pool. This was about 300-400MB per pool.

After the memory upgrade the same pools now claimed 600-800GB. We verified on our development machines with even more memory and there the claim got even higher (up to 1GB).

So now our in-house hoster things adding more memory does not make sense.

My questions: 
- Why are the pools taking memory relative to the physical memory (so it appears)? I could not find information about this, only that the maximum for private bytes is 60% of physical memory, not the actual claim would increase too for the same pool if more physical memory is added.
- How can we influence this? Is setting private byte limit per pool the solution?

We hoped to be able to add more customers to our server by adding more memory.

Best regards, Rob

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing an increase in **Standy** memory which is actually available. An interesting link with some related details is [Where has all my Physical RAM Gone?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/12/19/where-has-all-my-physical-ram-gone.aspx)

The related part is

> **Standby**: Pages of physical ram not actively being used. These are still left in physical ram but will be repurposed first by the memory
>   manager (either returned to the active list or zeroed out and reused)
>   if something needs physical ram for active pages. Standby pages are
>   essentially cache – it’s better to have infrequently used data kept in
>   RAM “just in case” than pushing it out to disk when the memory isn’t
>   needed for anything else.

In general it is the operating taking as much of it as it can, just in case it needs it. This happens on Windows 7 as well in a similar manner. A computer with a couple of browser tabs and Outlook open is using 5 GB of memory, but will free up unused portions as needed.

On a 2012R2 development server, I see something similar

[image]

As you mentioned, you can also limit the memory usage of an *App Pool* within IIS itself. It sounds like you may know how to do this but in case it helps you or others:

You can limit memory taken by an *App Pool*

- Open **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**
- Navigate to the **Application Pool** section
- Click once on the *App Pool* you'd like to limit
- On the right side under the **Actions** pane, click **Recycling...**
- Within the window that appears, you can choose your preferred options under **Memory Based Maximums**

[image]

In general I'm suspecting you'll be okay to add more customers to your server, unless you have some heavy hitting web applications currently running. You may consider setting a reasonable limit for the memory for a few App Pools and see if it has any effect on the application in terms of performance and test what works.

This will give you a better idea of how many additional customers you could host reasonably.

You may also want to set a limit to the App Pools in terms of memory to prevent customer sites from taking resources away from other customer sites. This of course completely depends on your environment and what type of loads the server handles at certain times.

Comment: Is standby memory part of what I see as claimed for a worker process (private bytes)? I think I cannot see standby parts for the worker processes?

Comment: I don't believe the private bytes will give you an accurate number. You probably want to look at "Working set private bytes." Use Process Explorer and check that number out for your processes. http://superuser.com/a/618811 seems to have a good explaination